# Using Selenium Scripts in a Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have recorded some Selenium Scripts using the Selenium IDE Firefox add-on.

I'd like to add these to the unit test cases for my Django project. Is it possible to somehow turn these into a Python unit test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are recording scripts in Python formatting, those are already converted to unit test cases. Save each scripts and run them in batch mode.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that option in the menu. That works perfectly. Thanks!